# Service Reference Update throws An expression is too long or complex to compile

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm getting the error "An expression is too long or complex to compile" when ever I attempt to update a .net Service Reference. I pulled up the Reference.cs of the service to see what was going on and it seems that Visual Studio is updating the service reference with an abstract class called GeneratedEDMModel. Basically this class is housing an extremely long concatenated xml string which the compiler seems to have problems with. It also seems environmental as others on the team are able to update the service just fine and this class isn't being generated. Deleting and creating a new service does the same thing and I've also tried with a o-data service and get the same behavior.

**Can anyone shed some light onto what this is and how it's being generated?**

I can't possibly paste the entire model string in here but here is a snippet of whats being written to the reference file. The const string ModelEdmx seems to be the entire EF model in xml form.

```
 [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    private abstract class GeneratedEdmModel
    {
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
        private static global::Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel ParsedModel = LoadModelFromString(ModelEdmx);
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
        private const string ModelEdmx = "<edmx:Edmx Version=\"1.0\" xmlns:edmx=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edm" +
            "x\"><edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion=\"1.0\" m:MaxDataServiceVersion=\"3.0\" x" +
            "mlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata\"><Schema " +
            "Namespace=\"Model\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm\"><Ent" +
            "ityType Name=\"AttachmentType\"><Key><PropertyRef Name=\"AttachmentTypeId\" /></Key>" +
            "<Property Name=\"AttachmentTypeId\" Type=\"Edm.Guid\" Nullable=\"false\" p6:StoreGener" +
```

Comment: you should check your service port and lunch port are same or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This had something to do with Visual Studio. A re-install of visual studio fixed the problem.